# Problemas ao tentar salvar no banco "POST" = "no-such-table" Django / Python

Tags: python, django, sqlite3, crud

Estou seguindo um curso de Python e Django, e o problema começa quando a versão no curso é 1.1.2 e a minha é 1.8.2

Consegui gerar um formulário para salvar "Eventos" porem, quando clica-se em submit, retorna os seguinte erro:

```
    OperationalError at /adiciona/
no such table: agenda_itemagenda
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/adiciona/
Django Version: 1.8.2
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such table: agenda_itemagenda
Exception Location: C:\wamp\www\curso python\aula\aula\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 318
Python Executable:  C:\wamp\www\curso python\aula\aula\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.9
Python Path:    
['C:\\wamp\\www\\curso python\\aula\\aula\\gerenciador',
 'C:\\wamp\\www\\curso python\\aula\\aula\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\wamp\\www\\curso python\\aula\\aula\\DLLs',
 'C:\\wamp\\www\\curso python\\aula\\aula\\lib',
 'C:\\wamp\\www\\curso python\\aula\\aula\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\wamp\\www\\curso python\\aula\\aula\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\wamp\\www\\curso python\\aula\\aula\\Scripts',
 'C:\\Python27\\Lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\wamp\\www\\curso python\\aula\\aula',
 'C:\\wamp\\www\\curso python\\aula\\aula\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 5 Jun 2015 01:10:35 -0300
```

**agenda.py**

```
from django.db import models

class ItemAgenda(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    data = models.DateField()
    hora = models.TimeField()
    descricao = models.TextField()`
```

**views.py**

```
    #-*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
# Create your views here.


from models import ItemAgenda
from forms import FormItemAgenda

def lista(request):
    lista_itens = ItemAgenda.objects.all()
    return render_to_response("lista.html", {'lista_itens': lista_itens})


def adiciona(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = FormItemAgenda(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            dados = form.cleaned_data
            item = ItemAgenda(
                    titulo=dados['titulo'],
                    data=dados['data'],
                    hora=dados['hora'],
                    descricao=dados['descricao']
                    )
            item.save()
            return render_to_response("salvo.html", {})
    else:
        form = FormItemAgenda()
    return render_to_response("adiciona.html", {'form': form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class FormItemAgenda(forms.Form):
    titulo = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    data = forms.DateField(
                widget=forms.DateInput(format='%d/%m/%Y'),
                input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y', '%d/%m/%y'])
    hora = forms.TimeField()
    descricao = forms.CharField()
# Create your models here.
```

**lista.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block corpo %}
<a href="/adiciona/"> Adicionar novo item </a>
<ul>
    {% for item in lista_item %}
    <li> 
        <a href="/item/{{ item.id }}">
            {{ item.data|date:'d/m/Y'}} - {{ item.titulo }}

        </a>
    </li>
    {% empty %}
    <li> Sem itens na lista</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

**adiciona.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

    {% block corpo %}

    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Adicionar</button>

    </form>

    {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 4):

O mais provável é que você esteja tentando usar um Banco de dados que ainda não foi atualizado. Você utilizou os comandos?

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py syncdb
```

Estes são para atualizar o BD com base no seu model.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Então, o problema era a compatibilidade entre as versões mesmo... consegui continuar sem problemas instalando a versão correta ! agradeço a atenção !

Answer (score 3):

Como diz a exceção, `no such table: agenda_itemagenda`, o problema é que não é possível achar a tabela que o seu aplicativo precisa. Você criou as tabelas que o professor está usando no seu curso? Você *tem* a DDL (em outras palavras, os comandos `CREATE TABLE` pra recriar o banco de dados) que estão sendo usados no seu curso? Se sim, você tem que alimentar esse arquivo para o SQLite de alguma forma, ou via linha de comando ou via outro script Python, e.g.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')  # arquivo com o banco de dados
c = conn.cursor()
with open('ddl.sql', 'r') as inputFile:  # arquivo com a DDL
    c.execute(inputFile.read())
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: o problema era incompatibilidade de versões, regredi meu Django para 1.2.1 e consegui prosseguir com o curso. agradeço !